# What's the contrapositive to the statement: a quadrilateral is a parallelogram if it is a rectangle

Tags: geometry, logic, proof-explanation

my hypothesis: a quadrilateral is a rectangle (p)

my conclusion: a quadrilateral is a parallelogram (q)

in other words:
if a quadrilateral is a rectangle then it is a parallelogram (p implies q) (which is a true statement)

so my contrapositive would be:
if a quadrilateral is not a parallelogram then it is not a rectangle (not q implies not p)

which to me seems like it's a false statement because a diamond would be a parallelogram but it is not a rectangle

so where do I go wrong? thanks for the help

Comment: Your example is not a counter example. You have to say : "A diamond is not a parallelogram then it's not a rectangle".
"$\text{not} (p) \rightarrow \text{not}(q)$" and not "$p \rightarrow \text{not}(q)$".

Comment: The statement "if a quadrilateral is not a parallelogram then it is not a rectangle" is correct.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense

Comment: Why is that a contradiction?  You statement is about quadrilaterals that are not rectangles.  As a diamond is not a quadrilateral that is not a rectangle your statement doesn't have anything at all to say about diamonds. .... Are you confusing your "if" statements with "if and only if" statements?  Or are you assuming $\lnot p\to \lnot q\implies p \to q$?  It doesn't.  "If I am not a mammal then I am not a walrus"  most certainly does *not* mean "If I *am* a mammal then I am a walrus".

Answer (score 1):

> if a quadrilateral is a rectangle then it is a parallelogram (**p
> implies q**) (which is a true statement)
>
> so my contrapositive would be: if a quadrilateral is not a
> parallelogram then it is not a rectangle (**not q implies not p**)

The above statements are indeed contrapositive of each other, but note that your natural-language sentences (which refer to *any* quadrilateral) actually translate as $$∀x\;(Px{\implies}Qx)\\∀x\;(\lnot Qx{\implies}\lnot Px)$$ instead.

> which to me seems like it's a false statement because a diamond would
> be a parallelogram but it is not a rectangle
>
> so where do I go wrong?

A diamond isn't a counterexample to your contrapositive statement; a legitimate counterexample (to either statement) would be some rectangle that isn't a parallelogram.